# Java Syntax Highlighting in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio

I need to configure Java syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code. So Syntax should be dim or faded when it wasn't used variable, instead of highlighting the code.

So I use current version of the java for VS code and its extensions. Extension or Plugins don't provides that attribute.

How can I configure the syntax to be dimmed?

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Even I was searching for this finally got an extension called [Java Server Pages(JSP)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pthorsson.vscode-jsp). But unfortunately this extension unmaintained by the developer but still worth it.

Link is [JSP Extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=pthorsson.vscode-jsp)